# How can we Reduce response time for face_recognition python script given below?

Tags: python-3.x, face-recognition, response-time

import face_recognition

known_image = face_recognition.load_image_file("passport.png")

unknown_image = face_recognition.load_image_file("myphoto.png")

biden_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(known_image)[0]

unknown_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(unknown_image)[0]

results = face_recognition.compare_faces([biden_encoding], unknown_encoding)

print(results)

Comment: Generally its taking 10 seconds to give output. Do I need to run this script on high configured GPU?

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") Please be aware this is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: I don't know this module at all, but if it was me, I would put some timing prints in there to see what was taking all the time as a first step.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend following Adrian at [pyimagesearch](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2021/05/01/what-is-face-recognition/). He's a Phd comp sci person that puts out ALOT of material for computer vision. I can gaurentee that the info you are looking for, he has a blog about it. Probably even different versions for how to put on a [rasp pi](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/category/raspberry-pi/) too like this home security [blog post](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/01/home-surveillance-and-motion-detection-with-the-raspberry-pi-python-and-opencv/). Good luck! His books are good too